# Can fixedColumns be used with paging and without scrolling vertically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a table with paging. 
I'm trying to fix certain columns, but don't want to get rid of the paging, I simply want to add horizontal scrolling, but not vertical.
Can this be done with the FixedColumns plugin?
I've tried specifying the options like this:

```
table.dataTable({
  autoWidth: false,
  ajax: "/Source",
  deferRender: true,

  //fixed Column
  scrollX: true,
  fixedColumns: {
        leftcolumns:1
  }
  //
}
```

Answer (score -2):

fix on your browser first using inspect element by changing CSS and then the final change in coding by writing *!Important** on CSS where you change. then you successfully set according to your wish.
simple replace dataTable CSS with custom CSS by writing **!important**.